# How to load the same website after redirecting subdomain to subdirectory htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain, subdirectory

I could redirect subdomain to subdirectory:

sub.domain.com > www.domain.com/sub

By using:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) www.domain.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```

However, the page at www.domain.com/sub displayed nothing but this:

```
Index of /sub
Parent Directory
Apache Server at www.domain.com Port 80
```

I have a working website with contents at sub.domain.com.
How can I load the same website and make it work at www.domain.com/sub ?

Thank you.

Comment: If the content is at `http://sub,domain.com`, why in the world are you redirecting **away** from where the content is? If you want the URL to read `http://www.domain.com/sub/` then move all the content there.

Comment: I would not ask this question if I simply move all the content there. Can anyone help?

Comment: So your content is at `sub.domain.com`, and when someone actually goes to the content, they get redirected to `www.domain.com/sub`, which would need to proxy the request *back* to `sub.domain.com` in order to get to the actual content, which then redirects to `www.domain.com/sub`, which would need to proxy again. You get a loop. You need to move your content, this is completely backwards approach.

Comment: I see what u mean and that could be a problem. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Jon is right, you need to move the content. Then you just need to fix your redirect by adding `http://` in front of the target domain to redirect incoming requests from the old subdomain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain.com/sub/$1 [R=301,L]
```